# Angular - HttpClient: Map Get method object result to array property

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I am calling an API that returns a JSON Object.  I need just the value of the array to map to a Observable .  If I call api that just returns the array my service call works.

Below is my sample code  ..

```
// my service call ..
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Show} from '../models/show';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }


  findAllShows(): Observable<Show[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Show[]>(`${someURL}/shows`)
  }
}
```

If the return is a JSON Object such as below this fails..

```
// Service API that FAILS ...
{
  "shows": [
    {
      "id": "123f9165-80a2-41d8-997a-aecc0bfb2e22",
      "modified": "2017-08-13 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show1"
    },
    {
      "id": "456f9165-80a2-41d8-997a-aecc0bfb2e22",
      "modified": "2017-08-14 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show2"
    },
    {
      "id": "789f9165-80a2-41d8-997a-aecc0bfb2e22",
      "modified": "2017-08-17 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now this one works if I just return the Array

```
// Service API that Works ...
[
    {
      "id": "123f9165-80a2-41d8-997a-aecc0bfb2e22",
      "modified": "2017-08-13 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show1"
    },
    {
      "id": "456f9165-80a2-41d8-997a-aecc0bfb2e22",
      "modified": "2017-08-14 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show2"
    },
    {
     "id": "789f9165-80a2-41d8-997a-aecc0bfb2e22",
      "modified": "2017-08-17 15:54:47",
      "name": "Main Show3"
    }
  ]
```

How do I map the JSON object Observable into an Array Observable???

Answer (score 29):

You can simply `.map()` your http call, which is an `Observable`, to return the data type that you want.

```
findAllShows(): Observable<Show[]> {
    return this.http
        .get(`${someURL}/shows`)
        .map(result=>result.shows)
}
```

Your `httpClient.get()` should return an `Observable`, which you have explicitly stated it thought `Observable<Show[]>`. You `.map()` is an operator that transform the observable into a new one.

More on `.map()` operator: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html

#### Update:

For RXJS version 6 and above, simply use `.pipe()` to pipe the `.map()` operator:

```
findAllShows(): Observable<Show[]> {
    return this.http
        .get(`${someURL}/shows`)
        .pipe(map(result=>result.shows))
}
```

Comment: I tried and got error...    Property 'shows' does not exist on type 'Response'  .

Comment: @Netwobble No, do not type cast it to type `Response`. See my edit.

Comment: 'map' function is still not available for `httpClient`

Comment: @ArunRedhu `httpClient.get()` should return an `Observable`, which us explicitly stated through`Observable<Show[]>`. The `.map()` is an operator that transform the observable into a new one.

Comment: get('') with no type parameter should return Observable<Object>. Try with .map(res => res['shows'])

Comment: @CozyAzure this should be the accepted answer, sad to see that OP overlooked this

Answer (score 13):

Latest `HttpClient` which should be used instead of `http` has no `map` method. You should first import it by `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`
Then you should use it this way:

```
this.http.get(`${someURL}/shows`).pipe(
        map(res => res['shows'])
    )
```

Comment: Make sure to have `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,` in your tsconfig.json file to suppress error TS7015.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks All,
I was able to find solution by combining responses from @ Arun Redhu by providing a transfer object interface that the server sends back.  Then solution provided by @CozyAzure by using the .map() to transform one Observable to the correct Observable Show[].

Full Solution below for those interested.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Contact} from '../models/show';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
// Use the new improved HttpClient over the Http
// import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http'; 
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

// Create a new transfer object to get data from server
interface ServerData {
  shows: Show[];
}

@Injectable()
export class ShowsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

// want Observable of Show[]
  findAllShows(): Observable<Show[]> {  
    // Request as transfer object <ServerData>
    return this.http
      .get<ServerData>(`${apiURL}/shows`)
     // Map to the proper Observable I need 
      .map(res => <Show[]>res.shows); 

  }
}
```

All great now!!!  Thanks . So depending on data returned I can either use directly or map to proper Observable I need.

Comment: lol, why <Show[]>? The .shows property in the map already has the wished type

Comment: I tried the above approach. I am getting the data in the service but not in the component. Can you show me how to call the service in the component?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`.map(res=> res['shows'] )`  does the trick

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yeah More info to why res.shows doesn't work but this works

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches of doing this. You can use `.map` operator form the observable to map one type of observable into another and second approach includes just with the help of interface.

1st Approaches (with the help of `.map`)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface ItemsResponseObj {
    id: string,
    modified: string,
    name: string
}

interface ItemsResponse {
    shows: Array<ItemsResponseObj>;
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData(): Observable<ItemsResponseObj[]> {
        return this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('api/api-data.json')
            .map(res => res.shows);
    }

}
```

and in the 2nd approach with the help of wrapping interfaces

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

interface ItemsResponseObj {
    id: string,
    modified: string,
    name: string
}

interface ItemsResponse {
    shows: Array<ItemsResponseObj>;
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData(): Observable<ItemsResponse> {
        return this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('api/api-data.json')
    }

}
```

Comment: creating a new interface just to wrap the data, and then unwrap it is not the best approach